# Matrix dimensions in Linear Algebra vs Time series Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, mathematical-statistics, linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

I am confused or may misunderstand the dimensions of a Matrix when I was reading about time series analysis.

From what I understand in linear Algebra, if we have a Matrix  $A \in \mathbf{R}^{m*n}$, this means $m$ refers to rows and $n$ refers to columns. But, when I was reading about multivariate time series, the notations kind of seem all the way around. They refer to $m$ as variables or features whereas $n$ as the length.

From my general understanding, if we have a number of instances $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbf{R}^{m*n}$, this means $m$ would be the dimension of matrix (column or number of variables) and $n$ would be the length (number of rows). This seems to me we have a transpose Matrix.

The inconsistent in notations kind of makes me thinking that I may misunderstand something. does this help in time series analysis or what is the intuition behind this.

Comment: Just to be clear, an matrix $A$ with dimensions $n\times p$ has $n$ rows and $p$ columns. Whether or not now the instances/items/time-series/subjects/what-have-you will be along the rows or the columns is primarily author (and editor) discretion. Usually we have the instances along the rows in linear regression (i.e. first row contains information for the first instance, second row contains information on the second instance, etc.) but that is not a hard rule.

Comment: Great! I would assume that it might depend on the algorithms used to analyse the data and how we should prepossess them beforehand.

Comment: Yes. As mentioned "usually" $n$ is the sample size and $p$ is the number of features/dimensionality of the samples/etc.

Comment: Awesome, it is more clear now.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a matter of convention of your instructor or a textbook to pick either the columns or rows of a matrix as variables. I've seen this done both ways. In econometrics it's more often to see variables in columns, i.e. $n$ variables in $R^{m\times n}$ matrix. I think ML papers it's often the rows with variables, i.e. $m$ variables with $n$ observations. Pay attention to the introduction of the paper to see which convention they use, that's all you can do

Comment: Please see 
https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6304/my-upvoting-policy, 
when you find a question sufficiently clear to 
write an answer, consider to upvote the question!